# Object Debugger 404 error

Tags: facebook, object, http-status-code-404

I have checked similar questions asked, but none seem to match the circumstances of this one.

[This page](http://austparents.edu.au/webinars/parent-webinar-on-the-australian-curriculum-with-rob-randall-ceo-acara/) is returning a 404 error in Facebook's Object Debugger tool. Other pages on the site work okay, so it shouldn't be any missing meta tags.

Now some of the page content is hidden, but only some, the majority of the page content is available, so surely this shouldn't be causing the issue. If it does then that would have to be regarded as a bug, no?

Anyone have any idea what the issue might be and/or how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is accurate - your URL is returning a 404 when the Facebook crawler attempts to get the metadata

You'll need to check your server settings or the code which renders that URL to see why it's doing so, here's the output when i made the same request Facebook makes from my own laptop:

```
$ curl -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1" -i  'http://austparents.edu.au/webinars/parent-webinar-on-the-australian-curriculum-with-rob-randall-ceo-acara/'
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Tue, 23 Sep 2014 00:03:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 366
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /webinars/parent-webinar-on-the-australian-curriculum-with-rob-randall-ceo-acara/
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at austparents.edu.au Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```